# Are the laws of classical physics different in Star Wars?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, physics

Star Wars is supposed to be set in the same universe as Earth, being a galaxy far, far, away.

Within the limited domain of classical physics, are the laws the same or different? We know in the other domains like quantum etc, it's clearly different, given the existence of hyperspace travel and all that, but what about in the routine day to day aspect, the laws of physics that directly affect daily life? Aerodynamics etc etc?

Comment: Explosions in the vacuum of space have fireballs and sound effects. So I'd assume physics is completely different there.

Comment: There's also music in space, like a Great Band of the Galaxy watching and waiting for something exciting to happen. (Imagine Brian Blessed's voice:) "ON YOUR TRUMPETS, MEN! THE BATTLE OF YAVIN IS ABOUT TO BEGIN!"

Comment: I'm pretty sure this planet Lola Sayu could not exist in this form in our universe.  Something broke it in half like an egg but it is still habitable.  http://i.stack.imgur.com/juXeSm.png

Answer (score 11):

At 9:26 in the "Mythology of Star Wars" interview below, Lucas talks about his attempts to create consistency in the Star Wars universe even if it's different from our own world, and he says that the presence of sound in space was meant as one of the rules of the Star Wars universe (as opposed to sound which is [non-diegetic](http://filmsound.org/terminology/diegetic.htm), something the audience can hear but characters in that universe wouldn't, like music and narration):

> One of the things I struggle for is to create a kind of immaculate realism in a totally unreal and fantasy world. It's a science that I can make up, but once I make up a rule then I have to live with it. ... One of the rules is that there's sound in space. So, there's sound in space, I can't suddenly have spaceships flying around without any sound anymore, because I've already done it. I've established that as one of the rules of my galaxy, and I have to live with that.

Edit: Apparently the people in charge of the new Disney canon were either unaware of this or chose to ignore it, since the canon novel [*Lords of the Sith*](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Lords_of_the_Sith) features a scene of Darth Vader pursuing another ship which includes the following line on [p. 17](http://books.google.com/books?id=qiPTCwAAQBAJ&lpg=PP1&pg=PA17):

> His ship slammed into the gun bubble and the transport, the inability of the vacuum to transmit sound causing the collision to occur in eerie silence.

Comment: As usual, George Lucas FTW. What do the characters think of this? Does it puzzle them that this does not fit with the rest of their physics? Do they blame it on the Force? Can the Force transmit sound?

Comment: @Jonah This isn't consistently followed at all. Most authors try to avoid the topic of sound in space. When it comes up, they may acknowledge the character can't hear something that they're seeing, or say that the ship's computer is emulating noises to add more feedback for the crew/pilot.

Comment: Timothy Zahn for one Just relates it to as recordings from hull contact, when he did mention it in 'Thrawn".  Most authors just try to ignore it, Though some of the better books I have read give a reasonable explanation for it.  In the book the "sounds of Star Wars", Lucas says that he has the ability to do whatever he wants, as this all takes place in 'Galaxy far, far away' and that maybe there are 100 hydrogen molecules per cubic mm instead of 20, so their is the ability to conduct sound. As for the music, I quote, "Maybe I placed on orchestra on an adjacent asteroid',Though this is a joke.

Comment: Additionally I was reading a book, I think it might have been 'Catalyst', And I think it said something about having devices that simulate space combat sounds so that the pilots have some idea of what is happening.